# jsfiddle code sample for UI5 Web Components using unpkg.com to avoid dependency on npm

Tags: npm, web-component, unpkg, ui5-webcomponents

A question for the [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com) nerds.

I'd like to create a code sample for [UI5 Web Components](https://sap.github.io/ui5-webcomponents/playground/) on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net). The goal is to share code samples without forcing readers to install the corresponding NPM module and its dependencies.

The corresponding node package [@ui5/webcomponents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ui5/webcomponents) can be installed with npm:

```
npm install @ui5/webcomponents
```

then I can import the desired web component:

```js
import "@ui5/webcomponents/dist/Button"; // loads ui5-button
```

and instantiate the custom element in an HTML page:

```html
<ui5-button>Hello world!</ui5-button>
```

How can I host this code sample on jsfiddle so that the "Hello world" button is displayed there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `?module` parameter (from [the unpkg docs](https://unpkg.com/)):

```
?module
Expands all “bare” import specifiers in JavaScript modules to unpkg URLs. This feature is *very experimental*
```

so at a bare minimum:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ui5/webcomponents/dist/Button?module" type="module"></script>

<ui5-button>Hello world!</ui5-button>
```

Here it is on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jognum9a/).

Alternatively you can import it directly as a module:

```
<ui5-button>Hello world!</ui5-button>

<script type="module">
    import 'https://unpkg.com/@ui5/webcomponents/dist/Button?module';
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhmfwjq2/)

Note the '**very experimental**' qualifier in the docs, so I wouldn't rely on it quite yet!